# Проблема с Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

Перестала запускаться Raspberry Pi 2 после того, как залез в raspi-config и поставил в настройках памяти значение 16, а также включил SSH. Зависает при загрузке на строке:

> [OK] Started udev Kernel Device Manager

Стоит Raspbian Stretch Lite, версия 07.09.2017
Как исправить?

UPD1
Через несколько минут пишет

> [OK] Started Load/Save Random Seed

и зависает снова

UPD2
И еще через несколько

> [FAILED] Failed to start Flush Journal to Persistent Storage See 'systemctl status systemd-journal-flush.service' for details

Comment: Через несколько минут пишет [OK] Started Load/Save Random Seed и зависает снова

Comment: И еще через несколько [FAILED] Failed to start Flush Journal to Persistent Storage See 'systemctl status systemd-journal-flush.service' for details

Comment: Может стоит переустановить ОС?